# GetRequestStream Stopping in Array

Tags: c#, web-services, post, get-request

I have a list of json strings that I am trying to loop through and post to a WebService. It loops through the first two just fine, then just stops on the 3rd iteration (this happens on line 14). No errors or anything, it just seems to stop. Any ideas?

```
    private static void CacheGetDataUrl(Guid sessionGuid)
    {
        var tokens = Driver.GetDataPostValues();
        foreach (var token in tokens)
        {
            try
            {
                var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token.Replace("session_identifier", sessionGuid.ToString()));
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(GetDataUrl);
                request.Timeout = 1000000;
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
                using (var postData = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    postData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    postData.Close();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Response requested for URL {0}", GetDataUrl); 
                Log.Info(String.Format("Response requested for URL {0} using parameters \r\n{1}", GetDataUrl, token));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error occurred requesting response for URL {0} using parameters \r\n{1}", GetDataUrl, token);
                Log.Error(String.Format("Error occurred requesting response for URL {0} using parameters \r\n{1}", GetDataUrl, token));
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altering the method with a few new properties, and aborting the request after it's received seems to have resolved the problem.

```
    private static void CacheGetDataUrl(Guid sessionGuid)
    {
        var tokens = Driver.GetDataPostValues();
        foreach (var token in tokens)
        {
            try
            {
                var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token.Replace("session_identifier", sessionGuid.ToString()));
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(GetDataUrl);
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
                request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
                request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 250;
                using (var postData = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    postData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    postData.Close();
                }

                request.Abort();

                Console.WriteLine("Response requested for URL {0}", GetDataUrl); 
                Log.Info(String.Format("Response requested for URL {0} using parameters \r\n{1}", GetDataUrl, token));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error occurred requesting response for URL {0} using parameters \r\n{1}", GetDataUrl, token);
                Log.Error(String.Format("Error occurred requesting response for URL {0} using parameters \r\n{1}", GetDataUrl, token));
            }
        }
    }
```